# How to use typeorm find and update multi datas

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

For example

```
@Entity("user")
export class UserEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @Column()
  corpName: string;
}
```

now I want to replace all datas like "corpName:google", "corpName:microsorft" with "corpName:Google", "corpName:Microsorft". Find and Update.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an entity named `UserEntity`, to find and update multiple data you need to use a service for code logic *(update)* and a repository to query your database *(find)*.

`user.entity.ts`

```
@Entity("user")
export class UserEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @Column()
  corpName: string;
}
```

`user.service.ts`

```
import { UserRepository } from './user.repository';

@Injectable
export class UserService {
  constructor(private userRepository: UserRepository) {}
  
  async updateData() {
    const data = await this.userRepository.find();

    // your code logic to replace your strings, use data.corpName.
  }
}
```

`user.repository.ts`

```
@EntityRepository(UserEntity)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<UserEntity> {}
```

> Code logic should never be in the repository or in the entity.

Comment: Thanks，What I really want to know is  the code logic to replace my strings, something like:` let user = await this.userRepository.find({corpName:new RegExp()});
    user.corpName = something + otherthing;
    await this.userRepository.save(user);`

Comment: Stackoverflow is used to solve problems, not providing you the code logic on demand. Try something with `map()` or `forEach()` to update your data and if you don't succeed, don't hesitate to post your code by editing the question !

Comment: Thanks, That's it, use map() or forEach() to update multi datas. :)